# Share cookies over folders

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

Can I share a cookie (set, read and update it) between two directions of mi website, for example, localhost/mysite/path1 and localhost/mysite/path2, using javascrit or jquery?

UPDATE

I'm trying to do this:

1.- In localhost/mysite/index.php set a cookie with an array in json:

```
  $.cookie("cart", cart_json, { expires: date}, {path: "/"});
```

2.- In localhost/mysite/folder/file.php both read and modified it with another array in json:

```
a = $.cookie("cart")
#manipulate a and save it in new_cart_json
$.cookie("cart", new_cart_json, { expires: date}, {path: "/"});
```

3.- I back to localhost/mysite/index.php, try to read the cookie and as result have the content put in cart_json. I check the cookies and now I have 2 cookies called "cart": One in the path /mysite and anothe in the path /mysite/folder

Comment: If this is the case, please use Local storage by passing your data to Javascript to do so.

Comment: I will have the same problem if i try it in my website, where i can't use local storage for save data in user's computer. I need use cookies for this issue.

Comment: make sure you set the domain to localhost and path to "/". This way all your cookies will be stored under root path and will be available to all paths that are nested in root.